# How to validate a phone number with + symbol in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, validation, phone-number

I am so confused about the regex methods. My requirement is to validate a phone number that may contains + symbol in its prefix. Then all the charactors should be numerals only. For this, how can i create a regular expression in objective c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say this is a definitive answer but it should give you a start.

```
^\x2b[0-9]+
```

Will match any string that starts with a '+' and then any amount of numbers greater than 0.

For instance:

```
+441312002000  - Full phone number matched.
+4413120c2000  - +4413120 is matched.
++441312002000 - No match 
441312002000   - No Match
```

If there are further constraints on length etc then specifiy and I can update the regex. I agree with other poster about using RegexKitLite.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... No matter about length. The second one that is, +4413120c2000 should not get matched & the last one 441312002000 should get matched because the plus symbol is an optional one

Comment: Yeah, you just need to add the end of line anchor and you should be fine. ^\x2b?[0-9]+$ should match the first and the last above but not the two in the middle.

Comment: Really? It does for me. How are you implementing it?

Comment: Your NSString that you create your regex from should look like: NSString *str = @"^\\x2b?[0-9]+$";

Answer (score 3):

I'm late answering, but I found an interesting solution when I recently have had the same problem. It uses the built-in cocoa methods instead of custom regex.

```
- (BOOL)validatePhoneNumberWithString:(NSString *)string {
    if (nil == string || ([string length] < 2 ) )
        return NO;

    NSError *error;
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber) {
            NSString *phoneNumber = [match phoneNumber];
            if ([string isEqualToString:phoneNumber]) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RegexKitLite, check the following http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/

Comment: Pradeepa, i saw your link. It has so many information. Thank you. But still i did not get the needed expression

Answer (score 0):

```
^\+?[0-9]*$
```

should do:

```
^      # start of string
\+?    # match zero or one + characters
[0-9]* # match any number of digits
$      # end of string
```

To use the regex in a string, you'll need to double the backslashes: `@"^\\+?[0-9]*$"` should work according to other regex examples I've seen, but I don't know Objective-C and may be wrong about this.

Comment: \+? is probably better. Matches 0 or 1 of the '+' character but not more. You don't want to end up matching ++++++++++++++++++445552002000 etc.

Comment: @Rajkanth: I've edited my answer using an alternative notation for ASCII digits - try this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But again it shows an error message as "Unknown escape sequence /+' :(

Comment: Which regex implementation are you using? Strange that it's showing slashes instead of backslashes in your error message, too.

Comment: I am really sorry... It shows the \ only. "Unknown escape sequence \+"

Answer (score 0):

`+*[0-9]{length of phone}`. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

This post nicely explains the regex -- http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/validate-phone-number.  You have to use "\" instead of "\" to prevent the Objective C preprocessor from interpreting regex escape codes as character string escape codes.

Here is the NSString you would use for the requested match

```
NSString *northAmRegexWithOptionalLeadingOne = @"^(?:\\+?1[-. ]?)?\\(?([2-9][0-8][0-9])\\)?[-. ]?([2-9][0-9]{2})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$";
```

Comment: I just noticed that the editor changed my double backslash to a single backslash?  The sentence should read "You have to use \\ instead of \"